# Does an ng-click trigger a $stateChangeStart?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `Angular UI Router` and I have a very simple:

```
  <a href='#' ng-click="toggleCollapse()">
    <i class="icon icon-triangle-down" ng-class="{'icon-triangle-down': !isCollapsed,
'icon-triangle-right': isCollapsed}"></i>
  </a>
```

My function looks like:

```
$scope.toggleCollapse = ->
  alert 'here'
  console.log $scope.isCollapsed
  $scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed
```

However, for some reason, my

```
$rootScope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (event, next, nextParams) ->
  console.log event
```

gets triggered when I click the link. Is there any way to prevent it from triggering the `$stateChangeStart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you have `href='#'` tag.

```
 <a ng-click="toggleCollapse()">
    <i class="icon icon-triangle-down" ng-class="{'icon-triangle-down': !isCollapsed,
'icon-triangle-right': isCollapsed}"></i>
  </a>
```

remove href that and it wont trigger route change